# Convert html code into plain text

Tags: java, android, html

I am developing android application in which i want to convert html code in to plain text and display it in the editText. I use Jsoup.jar for that but it shrink the data. Like it just remove the  tag.I will not got to the next line. Does any one has the solution to display html code in the plain text? Any help or suggestions are accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml(htmltext)`.